# Добавление уникальных значений в ключи массива

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста как собрать уникальный массив на основе ключа ["ID"]

С добавление в дублирующийся ключ например RGB_NAME значения из другова RGB_NAME

На входе такой массив

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(6) "126179"
    ["RGB_NAME"]=>
    string(14) "Бежевый"
    ["STYLE_NAME"]=>
    string(14) "Горох"
    ["COUNTRIES_TAKE"]=>
    string(12) "Россия"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(6) "126179"
    ["RGB_NAME"]=>
    string(10) "Белый"
    ["STYLE_NAME"]=>
    string(14) "Цветы"     
    
  }
}
```

На выходе должен получится такой

```
[0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(6) "126179"
    ["RGB_NAME"]=>
    array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "Бежевый" 
    [1]=>
    string(1) "Белый"
    }
    ["STYLE_NAME"]=>
    array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "Цветы" 
    [1]=>
    string(1) "Горох"
    }
    ["COUNTRIES_TAKE"]=>
    string(12) "Россия" 
  }
```

Comment: Объединяйте элементы с нужным ID через [array_merge_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

Comment: А можно какой то пример пожалуйста?
Просто у меня массив 1 а не два

Сейчас взял пример с этого ответа
https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.b687eb08-62cc09a8-4d34cc3b-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/a/29401335


foreach($elements2_1 as $k => $v){
        $sorted_array["$v[ID]"]=$v;
    }

Но это сливает два массива в 1
Но значения ключа берется последние а не добавляется я получаю такой

["RGB_NAME"]=>
    string(16) "Капучино"

заместо 

["RGB_NAME"]=>
    array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "Бежевый" 
    [1]=>
    string(1) "Белый"
    }